# Align figures at top in beamer

Tags: beamer, captions, positioning, includegraphics

I have several frames containing figures of the same size but captions of different length. The code I'm currently using is something like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{image1}
        \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
    \end{figure}    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{image2}    
        \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

The result is that the two figures are not in the same location inside their respective frames: the first one has a wider top margin than the second one.

How can I align those figures at top so that they will occupy the same space in each frame?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a \ vfill` seems to do the trick:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{image1}
   \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
 \end{figure}
\vfill\null
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{image2}
        \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
 \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I can see how it should work but in my case the problem is still there. It seems that `\vfill` doesn't work. How can this be?

Comment: Did you add  `\null` (or `\mbox{}`)  afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I added `\vfill\null`

Comment: Just in case:`leavevmode` just before `vfill`. If it isn't enough, you should post a minimal example reproducing the problem. Oh!  b.t.w., do you also have the problem with just my code?

Comment: Using `demo` option it works but removing that it doesn't neither with `\leavevmode`. I tried to replace `\null` with `a` and in each frame it appears at different distance from bottom as if the height of each frame is not always the same.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/1hTaOBm) is what I get.

Comment: I tested with real images from `mwe`, and it works adding `vfill\null` also in the second frame. Could you check if it works in your case?

Comment: I tried with `example-image-a.png` image but it doesn't work. It's not a big deal but it's quite strange.

Comment: That is strange because I tried with two mages from mwe, with  different heights (example-image-a and example-image-16x9), and it works.

Comment: These are the settings and packages I use (I don't know if it could help): `% !TeX program = lualatex`, `\documentclass[11pt, xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}`, `\usetheme{Madrid}`, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, `\usepackage[italian]{babel}`, `\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}`, `\usepackage{changepage}`, `\usepackage{hanging}`, `\usepackage{luacode}`

Comment: I've just tested with your preamble, and it sull works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact output you want to achieve, you could also add the `[t]` option to the `frame` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{image1}
   \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
 \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
 \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{image2}
        \caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
 \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```